# ¿Como gestionar datos de otras tablas en mysql?

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, netbeans

busco ayuda ya que necesito tomar el dato de numero de documento de una tabla, y placa de otra, ya las tengo hechas, ya que una sirve para registrar clientes y otra vehiculos, las hice separadas al igual que las consultas de estos, pero necesito crear un alquiler que tenga en cuenta el numero de documento de la tabla "clientes" y la placa de la tabla "automoviles", estoy usando XAMPP con mysql para la base de datos y lo estoy haciendo en netbeans.
Este es el try catch que utilizo dentro de un JButton para registrarlo en la tabla "clientes", el de la tabla "automoviles" es practicamente igual.

```
try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, clave);
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO clientes VALUES('"+tfNoDocumento.getText()+"' , '"+tfNombres.getText()+"' , '"+tfApellidos.getText()+"' , '"+tfNoContacto.getText()+"' , '"+tfDireccion.getText()+"')");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(registroAutos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se puede conectar a la base de datos");
    }
```

Como dije antes requiero esos 2 elementos de tablas distintas para realizar un registro en la otra tabla.

```
 try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, clave);
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM clientes INSERT INTO alquiler SELECT  Numero de documento="+tNDocumentoA.getText()); 
        stmt.executeUpdate("SELECT * FROM alquiler VALUES('"+tNDocumentoA.getText()+"' , 'UFE456' , '2004-05-07' , '2')");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(registroAutos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se puede conectar a la base de datos");
    }
```

Aqui intente hacerlo para el dato numero de documento poniendo el resto como valores fijos para probar, puse el "tNDocumentoA" ya que es el campo donde pondre el numero de documento para realizar el registro pero como necesito que ese dato haya estado previamente en la tabla "clientes" intente incluirlo a la tabla "alquiler" pero no funciono y no se como hacerlo. Ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 0):

UUHHm, te diria que la primera cosa de hacer es crear una Stored procedure que escriba o actualice la tabla "Alquiler" donde el valor de actualización provenga de la consulta relacionada entre cliente y automovil.

Osea, realices tu consulta que relacione clientes con automoviles, me imagino que uno de las 2 tablas tenga el ID de la otra tabla.... el resultado sera guardado en parametros que seran enviados a la stored procedure que realizara la actualizacion